# How do foreign business owners quickly find Thai citizens to employ?

Tags: thailand

In Bangkok around Sukumvit there are many many restaurants owned by foreigners (who don't speak Thai).

Each such business must have at least four Thai citizen workers on every foreigner worker although these businesses employ many non Thais.

How do foreign business owners quickly find Thai citizens to employ?

I ask this because many companies of foreigners here quickly have businesses closed and opened (the same company closes and opens new business each year or two years) and I just wonder how do they find Thai workers (in the large numbers Thai law requires) so fast and so efficient?

Often many of the workers aren't Thai but Burmese nationals (Myanmar passport).

I would theorize that human resources companies work hand in hand with lawyers in Thailand to aid such businesses in finding workers fast, but I might be wrong.